# Language prefix in email template path Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email

I am currently building a Magento 2 module. I defined adminhtml/system.xml file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" translate="label" sortOrder="402" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="finance" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="template_status_notification" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Status notification email template</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="status_email_enabled">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>   
</config>
```

Then in email_templates.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
      <template id="payment_finance_template_status_notification" label="Finance Contract Status Notification" file="finance_status_notification.html" type="html" module="Company_Finance" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

But when I try to run this module, it always try to take the language prefix between section id and group id "payment_us_finance_template_status_notification". And I got this exception "payment_us_finance_template_status_notification" is not defined. I dont want to define email templates path with all languages prefix for my module

[image]

Did anyone get the same problem like me? Could you please give me some advices? How can this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is bug in `Magento_Paypal` module.

This module has plugin `Magento/Paypal/Model/Config/StructurePlugin.php` for extending configuration for using paypal coutries as new scope. This plugin affect config path for `payment` section by replacing 'payment' scope to `payment_%COUNTRY_CODE%`.

```
$isSectionChanged = $pathParts[0] == 'payment';
if ($isSectionChanged) {
    $requestedCountrySection = 'payment_' . strtolower($this->_helper->getConfigurationCountryCode());
    if (in_array($requestedCountrySection, self::getPaypalConfigCountries())) {
        $pathParts[0] = $requestedCountrySection;
    } else {
        $pathParts[0] = 'payment_other';
    }
}
```

In you case you define `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template` as `source_model`, which use config method `$element->getPath()` for retrieve default template id for your field. But `path` has been overridden by `Paypal` module and there are no template id with country scope.

I think, that this is bug of `Magento_Paypal`.
You can use your custom option source as workaround.

*Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template.php*

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Email;

class Template implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template
     */
    private $templateSource;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template $templateSource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template $templateSource
    ) {
        $this->templateSource = $templateSource;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->templateSource->setPath('my_default_template_id')->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

*adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
```